# Replace '\par' using regex in C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I want to replace `\par` from a variable in `C#` on exact match with an empty string.
Let's say, if the variable content is:

> this is a test \parameter and \par test\par test\para

I want the output to be:

> this is a test \parameter and test test\para

Could someone help me with the regex expression to do this?
I tried using `\b` for getting the exact word but since it involves an escape sequence, I'm getting an error.

Comment: "I tried...". Show us **exactly** what it is that you tried.

Comment: Unclear what you're asking... the string `\par` exists 4 times in that string. What are your specific criteria for filtering it out?

Comment: This seems like very much a regex question and not really very related to C#

Comment: It is easy with a regex, have you tried any? Tried `\b`? In a verbatim string literal? Please show.

Comment: Why Regex? `yourString = yourString.Replace(@"\par ", " ")` should work.

Comment: A hint could be to use \\ instead of \... it will escape the \

Comment: @FabianH.: Unless `\par` is followed with punctuation.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You are right. But the question is not very clear on that.

Comment: Wiktor & Fabian; the regex version of that would be (\\par ), but you would end up with this as the sentence: this is a test \parameter and testtest\para which would remove a space he did not wanted to remove.... and yes.. the question is unclear... please improve it

Comment: Bjorn, I believe the `\b` was used in the normal string literal. If it were used with a verbatim string literal, the question becomes a typo off-topic question. `@"\\par\b"` or `@"\s*\\par\b"` is the right answer.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Or, y'know... "\\\\par\\b". Yay for Leaning Toothpick Syndrome.

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;


string input = @"\par test\par test\para";
         string result = input.Replace(@"\par "," ");
```

Comment: This is incorrect. It won't work if there is punctuation after `\par`. And if you   are using a String.Replace why declare the RegularExpressions namespace?

Comment: Why does it use `System.Text.RegularExpressions` if the actual code doesn't even use regex?

Comment: @Thomas No it won't; the search string to replace ends on a space.

Comment: As Wiktor has pointed out, it doesn't work in case there is a punctuation mark

Comment: @user2813853 As I poined out in the original comments though, you never actually specified your criteria.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use:

```
 string output= @"this is a test \parameter and \par test\par test\para".Replace(@" \par ", " ").Replace(@"\par ", " ");
```

using Regex, this may help you:

```
string input = @"\b( \\par |\\par )\b";

            var replaced = Regex.Replace(@"this is a test \parameter and \par test\par test\para", input, @" ");
```